# OpenJFX application fails to launch using Scala

Tags: scala, javafx

Launching following application fails with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dev.buildingdragons.dragon.Dragon$.<init>()` (find the full stack trace below).

To me, it looks like there is a constructor missing, but which? And Why?

I do now there are projects like ScalaFX but before using them I want to fully understand what is going on so I really want to create a walking skeleton.

Environment:

- Windows 10 Professional
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.1.2
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.2+3 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

Dragon.scala:

```
package dev.buildingdragons.dragon

import javafx.application.{Application, Platform}
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.stage.Stage

object Dragon extends Application {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = Application.launch(args: _*)

  override def start(stage: Stage): Unit = {
    val scene = new Scene(new Button("Test"))

    stage.setTitle("Hello, Dragon!")
    stage.setScene(scene)
    stage.showAndWait()

    Platform.exit()
  }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

compileScala.targetCompatibility = 1.8

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.8'
    compile 'org.scalafx:scalafx_2.12:11-R16'
}

javafx {
    version = "11.0.2"
    modules = ['javafx.controls']
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class dev.buildingdragons.dragon.Dragon$
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:890)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: dev.buildingdragons.dragon.Dragon$.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:801)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
```

**EDIT:** As suggested by [eugene-ryzhikov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112877/eugene-ryzhikov) I modified Dragon.scala:

```
package dev.buildingdragons.dragon

import javafx.application.{Application, Platform}
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.stage.Stage

class Dragon extends Application {
  override def start(stage: Stage): Unit = {
    val scene = new Scene(new Button("Test"))

    stage.setTitle("Hello, Dragon!")
    stage.setScene(scene)
    stage.showAndWait()

    Platform.exit()
  }
}

object Dragon {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = Application.launch(classOf[Dragon],  args: _*)
}
```

That solved the original problem but now I ran into the problem I was afraid of: Java's Project Jigsaw:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x4e08e183) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x4e08e183
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at dev.buildingdragons.dragon.Dragon.start(Dragon.scala:10)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application dev.buildingdragons.dragon.Dragon
```

I believe that is due to the fact that Scala does not enforce module restrictions at compile time but the JVM does at runtime.

Comment: Now you have to introduce `module-info.java` definition in your code to let JVM know which modules/resources you are importing and which ones you're exporting. Correct definition should solve your latest problem

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov Where would I put this? Could you please provide a module-info.java which works for my example? I tried now for hours but I get different problems and errors.

Comment: There is a lot of documentation around about the subject. Here is one https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start. In your case you just need to import `javafx` libraries. Also make sure you run under JDK 11+

Comment: Something like the following should do:

module dev.buildingdragons.dragon {
    requires javafx.controls;
    exports dev.buildingdragons.dragon;
}

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov That is what I tried, but if I place it at the `scala` folder I get a "Error:(1, 8) illegal start of type declaration module dragon.main {".

If I put the `module-info.java` into a `java` folder I get either a compiler error (when using Gradle to compile) or an IntelliJ error if I try to run it within IntelliJ.

Comment: Make sure you use JDK 11+ and set your compiler level to the same version. I would keep you module info on in java folder.

Comment: @EugeneRyzhikov Like `compileScala.targetCompatibility = 11` in the gradle.build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is the consequence of having your `start` method within the object. Move it to the new `Dragon` class with `main` method in the companion `Dragon` object. Also use the `launch` method where you can pass the application class.